# How do I change the position of circles made in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

Beginner question here and I would post all the code here but I believe the syntax is different as i am using codeHS to learn Javascript.

If I made circles using a for loop such as

```
for (var i = 0; i < NUM_CIRCLES; i++) {

    var circle = new Circle(RADIUS);
    var x = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getWidth() - RADIUS);
    var y = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getHeight() - RADIUS);
    circle.setPosition(x, y);
    circle.setColor(Randomizer.nextColor());
    add(circle);

}
```

If i later wanted to change the positions of one of the circles how would i do that? The circles are all made with the var circle so if use `circle.setPosition(x,y)` how do i tell it which circle to modify? or would i have to create a variable for every circle so their positions could be modified.

Answer (score 1):

keeping a tally of your circle objects, you can access them by position in the array or an identifier you can add to the object

```
var circleAggregator = [];
for (var i = 0; i < NUM_CIRCLES; i++) {
    var circle = new Circle(RADIUS);
    circleAggregator.push(circle); // index used as identifier
    // you can add another identifier by updating constructor
    var x = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getWidth() - RADIUS);
    var y = Randomizer.nextInt(RADIUS, getHeight() - RADIUS);
    circle.setPosition(x, y);
    circle.setColor(Randomizer.nextColor());
    add(circle);
}
```

... later when you want to access your object, find it by it's identifier, which in this case is the index

```
var selectedCircle = circleAggregator[idx];
```

or with an update method

```
updateCirclePosition(circleAggregator[idx]);
```